# "error: parser: instruction expected" when I use "org 0x0100" directive

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, dos, x86-16

I have this *NASM* code:

*Note that this is the original code before correcting my first error (see edit below):*

```
[org 0x0100]
       jmp start
Numbers: dw 10, 40, 20, 14, 19, 13, 50, 6, 60, 14
swap: db 0
start: mov bx, 0                                                          
       mov byte [swap], 0
loop1: mov ax, [Numbers+bx]                                                              
       cmp ax, [Numbers+bx+2]                                  
       jle noswap                                                            
       mov dx, [Numbers+bx+2]                                  
       mov [Numbers+bx+2], ax                                  
       mov [Numbers+bx], dx                                        
       mov byte [swap], 1                                              
noswap: add bx, 2                                                                
        cmp bx, 18                                                              
        jne loop1                                                                  
        mov ax, 0x4c00                                                        
        int 0x21
```

I am using this command to assemble:

```
nasm -f elf Max.asm
```

I get this error:

> error: unrecognized directive org

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** After removing the brackets around the `org` statement as suggested in the comments, I am now getting this error instead:

> Max.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected

Comment: Should  be `org 0x0100` as per the [manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.1) (ie. no brackets). Next time please don't post code as image. I VTC as a typo.

Comment: removed brackets but now got this 
Max.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected

and sorry for posting image :)

Comment: Note that `org` does not work with `elf` format. If you intend to create a linux program, delete the `org` line. If you intend to create a DOS program, remove the `-f elf`.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to compile to a DOS COM program. You'd have to compile it this way: `nasm -f bin Max.asm -o Max.com` .As Jester pointed out you can't use `-f elf` and `org 0x100`. The `org` directive only applies to the `-f bin`

Comment: Well, showing your code would be an awesome start.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer  this is code 

http://pastebin.com/VcWiTjMX

Comment: Minimum verifiable code examples must be posted here or they aren't helpful. Can you guarantee that that Pastebin link will remain valid for the next five years??

Comment: too long by 439 characters

this is message that i got when i want to paste code here ?

and according to pastebin 
we can set expire time 
@DavidHoelzer

Comment: you don't want to add the code into the Comments, do you? *sigh*

Comment: Are you targeting your executables for a 16-bit MS-DOS environment or are you trying to create an exectuable that runs on Linux? This code if compiled as `nasm -f bin Max.asm -o Max.com` would only be runnable in an environment that supports 16-bit MS-DOS programs (DOSBox etc).. If you are trying to create a Linux executable that runs natively in Linux then this won't work. MS-DOS interrupts like `int 0x21` don't apply.

Comment: Your code goes into the original question, not into the comments. Thanks Mr. Petch.

Comment: so i have to run this on windows ?
is there any other way to run this on Linux ?

Comment: DOS, not Windows. Int21 is a function dispatcher for DOS. on Linux, easiest way would be to use DosBox, I think

Comment: FYI: I modified the question so that the original error is still there, and the new error is added, because otherwise the question doesn't make sense anymore without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The originate directive tells the assembler to initialise all offsets for data and code in the program from given value.

`org 0x0100` is used when writing small(Normally .COM files) DOS programs to compensate for the `PSP(Program Statement Prefix)`.

If you are working on linux, there is no point in adding the orginate directive.

`nasm -f bin max.asm`

will work, but then it can be executed only in DOSBOX.